# Best Unicode characters for line graph containing 45° angles

Tags: unicode, graph

I am writing code that draws a simple line graph to the Console, and can use Unicode characters. I am looking for the best way to encode 45° angled lines into my graphs.

For instance, here's a 2x2 block of Unicode characters, representing a 45° angled line intersecting a vertical line:

```
│ 
│╲
```

In an ideal world, I'd like to find a set of Unicode characters which fits in the same 2x2 space and touches the edges in the same spots, but the diagonal line reaches all the way to the vertical one somehow.

The closest thing I've found is that you could replace the vertical line with `▕`, like this, but then the vertical bar won't touch the edges in the same spots, so it won't cleanly fit the rest of the graph.

```
▕ 
▕╲
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: It also depends upon the used font

Comment: Assume this is being output to a monospace terminal.

Comment: But even the font vertical appearance matters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about graphic design, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

Different fonts draw "one eighth block" differently, so you just need to choose the font that better suits your needs, e.g.:

[image: Hack font] - Hack font

[image: Segoe UI] - Segoe UI

[image: MS Gothic] - MS Gothic

**Other characters, that may be come in handy:**

- U+2595: `▕` (Right one eighth block)
- U+258F: `▏` (Left one eighth block)
- U+2571: `╱` (Light diagonal upper right to lower left)
- U+2572: `╲` (Light diagonal upper left to lower right)
- U+2573: `╳` (Light diagonal cross)

More drawing characters:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Answer (score 1):

one of these might work. The Font is the Symbola Font. The Hex column is the hex representation for the unicode font shown on the right.

[image]

Comment: These characters don't reach the edge of the character box or line up with the existing lines, unfortunately :(